# How to create dialog with custom subtitle and some buttons

Tags: android, dialog

Check out this image

[image]

How do I create such a dialog? Having 2 line subtitle and three distinctive buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this picture was created with a dialog which was defined in a XML file and then added to the dialog by calling setContenView().

The method is described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

isn't this working for you? If not I think you would have to extend the Dialog class and implement your own.